# jQuery append Not Working in Double HTML

Tags: jquery

I have a code with a two steps. The following statement:

**Step 1:** If the `<span id="test"></span>` no text, then `id='parent'` will be removed with this code `$("#parent").Remove();`

**Step 2:** If the `id="container"` no text, then `id="container"` will automatically generate text **NO DATA** with this code `$("#container").append("NO DATA");`

At Atep 1 work well. But at this Step 2 not working.
I also had to replace of `append()` into `html()` and has not been able to work.
What's the solution?

**My Codes:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'>

<div id='parent'>
<b>Age:</b> <span id='test'></span>
</div>

</div>

<script>
if($("#test").html()==""){
$("#parent").remove();
}

if($("#container").html()==""){
$("#container").append("NO DATA");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's whitespaces left in your container so `html()` is not empty you need to use `$.trim()` to remove left whitespaces. Here's [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lovx5uwL/) for you.

```js
if($("#test").html()==""){
$("#parent").remove();
}
if($.trim($("#container").html())==""){
$("#container").append("NO DATA");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>

<div id='parent'>
<b>Age:</b> <span id='test'></span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, I need to learn from you. Thank you for helping me :)